# Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.R$style"

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a project which has can use facebook login. Sometimes I get the following exception:

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.R$style"...
```

After a clean and rebuild, often solves the issue. Have anyone encountered this issue, and managed to solve it? Sidenote: The project is fairly large, and uses multi-dexing.

Comment: Same problem. Have you managed to resolve this?

Comment: Just had a longer vacation - but according to the android developers page about multidexing - I believe you need to include a MultiDexKeepFile, in order to ensure the facebook classes are a part of the primary dex file: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Thanks for the info. We don't use MultiDex but a tight Proguard configuration. Just cleaned solution, and it works now.